# Entry doesn't work in two layers of ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-entry

I noticed an odd issue while using Xamarin Forms. Let's say I have two `ListView`s one inside another and each have an `Entry`. At first, the inside text box doesn't work (when you tap it, the cursor doesn't stay in the box and no keyboard popup). However, the entry in the outer listview works fine. Once you click on the outer entry, the inner one then starts working.

Here is a git I created to demo the issue: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/entry_issue

Comment: Why are you not using Grouping?

Comment: nesting ListViews is always a horrible idea and you should find an alternate method

Comment: Wasn't using it since I hadn't heard of it. Looking into it now, thanks. However, this looks like a very specific solution (two level tree structure). how about if there were three levels of lists. As of now all I can think of is merging this with some manual components

Comment: If you have multiple level in listview.You can use some third part package .Such as https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thanks, I am using a manual loop for now. made more sense than all these